# C++ Error to Read byte line

Tags: c++, char, byte, line

I'm trying to make the program read the text file and use the line for function, but I get an error!

```
5   IntelliSense: operand types are incompatible ("BYTE" and "char *")
Error   1   error C2446: '==' : no conversion from 'char *' to 'int'
Error   2   error C2040: '==' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'char [260]'
```

my code:

```
char* ReadINI(char* szSection, char* szKey, const char* szDefaultValue)
{
    char* szResult = new char[255];
    memset(szResult, 0x00, 255);
    GetPrivateProfileString(szSection, szKey, szDefaultValue, szResult, 255, ".\\Config.ini");
    return szResult;
}

int main (Classdata* Cdata)
{
    BYTE ByteID = Cdata->ByteType;
    static char ReadByte[MAX_PATH];
    sprintf(ReadByte, "%s", ReadINI("CONFIG", "Key", "0"));

    if (ByteID == ReadByte)
    {
        printf("Byte Value: %p", ReadByte);
    }
}
```

Comment: 'Use the line for function' and your title are meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are comparing ByteId (an `unsigned char` `) with ReadByte (a char*) which is unlikely to be meaningful.

On an unrelated note, szResult is created with `new` but never `delete`d in main.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't be much clearer `ByteId` is a `BYTE`, `ReadByte` is a `char[260]`. You cannot compare integers and arrays. Perhaps (only a guess) you meant `ByteId == ReadByte[0]`.

Plus you have a memory leak in `ReadIni`, and `ReadByte` is declared static for no good reason I can see, and your declaration of `main` is not legal.

Answer (score -1):

I used another type of function to read the file! Sorry for the bad explanation is that I'm working on a private project! thanks for the help everyone

fuction:

```
UINT value = GetPrivateProfileInt("Section", "Key", DEFAULT_VALUE, "program.ini");
```

thx for all!

Comment: You could at least fix your question so it is intelligible. Or delete it.